# admin template selection is missing on page creation in wordpress 3.2.x

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using WordPress 3.2.1 ,

Page template selection drop down is missing on Pages (Add,Edit)

```
wp-admin > Pages >Add New > Page Attributes
```

I Edit the Template Page Default page as below code

```
/*
Template Name: New Template
*/
```

But still the template drop down no visible , my older version of WordPress it display by default.

Following is the screen shot for more idea
[image]

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem solved by adding the typical following code:

```
/*
Template Name: Custom
*/
```

Don't add any spaces after  `Name:`

It'll work if you use `template name:` as well.

Comment: if this right for you, please approve it as best answer. thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

It might help someone: check if your **index.php** file is in place.

If it's not there, wordpress treats the template as corrupt and it doesn't display the template selection.

Comment: Yes you are right , some file are corrupted , i give the comment @Jeremy Jared also , thanks ,+1 to you

Answer (score 2):

This should be simple to troubleshoot. The requirements for the page template to work are straight forward:

The template needs the page title in the top of the file like you've shown (the title needs to be wrapped in a PHP tag, you probably just didn't add it with your example bu I want to make sure you havne't overlooked it):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom
*/
?>
```

The second requirement is that the file is in the root of the theme folder.

With those two requirements in place, it should work. If it isn't working you nave a few possible issues. I list a few off the top of my head:

1. You might need to re-install WordPress in-case a file was corrupted
   during your last update.
2. It's possible someone has altered the WP-Admin layout using users
   roles.

That's all I can thing of at the moment, let me know how it turns out.

Comment: @thanks for your time,i got the problem because of i some file are **corrupted**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It actually turned out to be a missing style.css file within the template directory in my case. 
This happens because the get_post_templates() in class-wp-theme.php first checks for errors. If it finds any then it returns an empty array (no templates are displayed).

A side effect of this is that saving a page would clear the existing template and use the page.php instead.

So in short if the errors() method of your theme returns any errors then no templates dropdown.

hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Same issued, I found out that in appearance panel in your WordPress dashboard the stylesheet is missing. You shouldn't rename the style.css in your theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone, but we solved the problem by disabling our theme and re-enabling it again.  We had some other theme folders in the theme directory that we weren't using so we deleted those out as well. good luck, it's a really random problem to solve!

Comment: Thank you @deweydb , but in my case file got corrupted

Answer (score 0):

yeah!template dropdown not showing because you have no template So how to solve this::---

1 create template folder in theme
2 create a template in this folder
like:-
`<?php /* Template Name: Home */ echo "template"; ?>`

and check-in page dropdown will be there.